# Unable to connect to SQL Server Express container on host VM

Tags: docker, sql-server-express, windows-server-2016

I've been working to get SQL Server 2014 Express running in Windows Server 2016 TP5 via Windows Containers.

After following the guidelines [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2014-express-windows) I'm able to start a container with Sql Server Express and attach a database.

My full `docker run` command:

```
docker run -p 1433:1433 -v C:/temp/:C:/temp/ --env sa_password=xxxx --env attach_dbs="[{'dbName': 'Docker', 'dbFiles': ['C:\\temp\\Docker.mdf', 'C:\\temp\\Docker_log.ldf']}]" microsoft/msslq-server-2014-express-windows
```

However, I cannot figure out what piece I'm missing when attempting to connect SSMS on the host VM (Server 2016) to the container's SQL Server Express instance.

I'm using the default port (1433) for SQL Server in my `docker run` command.

Docker version on host VM is: `1.12.1, build 23cf638`

Window Server 2016 TP5 build is: `14300.rs1_release_sv.160907-0755`

Running `netstat -a` confirms that 1433 is being listened on in the container, but 1433 is *not* being listened on the host VM.

Running `docker ps` while the container is running confirms that port 1433 is mapped as `0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp`

To connect to the SQL Server instance in the container via SSMS on the host VM I'm using the `sa` user and set password with the internal IP address of the container that I retrieved with the following powershell:

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" <containerid>
```

Unfortunately, SSMS is unable to find the instance and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to specify the port as well as IP when connecting from the host VM.  I didn't think I needed to do that since I'm using the default sql server port.

Got the container IP from this command:

`docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" <containerid>`

Server name: "ip","port"\"instancename" worked and was able get in with both sqlcmd and SSMS on the host VM.

Comment: In riga:1 car:73
+ ... ct --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" <8cfa4ea2 ...
+                                                                 ~
Operatore '<' riservato per utilizzi futuri.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

Answer (score 0):

You can set an IP-Address for this docker and try to connect with this one:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.2:1433:1433 -v C:/temp/:C:/temp/ --env sa_password=xxxx --env attach_dbs="[{'dbName': 'Docker', 'dbFiles': ['C:\\temp\\Docker.mdf', 'C:\\temp\\Docker_log.ldf']}]" microsoft/msslq-server-2014-express-windows
```

Or any suitable IP-Address for your system. You can now use this address to connect to.

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: `Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint <container name> on network nat: Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings.`

Comment: Could you give the output of this command ? `docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"` will give you something like this `map[bridge:...` (bridge in my case)

Comment: result of that is: `map[nat:0xc08237a0c0]`